# GitHub: cancel a push from the remot repo

Tags: git, github, repository, push, commit

I had a repo on github called "A", with a local copy.
I then modified the name of the repo from "A" to "B" and assigned the former name ("A") to a new, different remote repo.
I forgot to correct the link on the local repo (`git remote set-url origin link`); so the local repo now is connected to the second remote repo (that took the name "A").
Without thinking about this i pushed a commit from local to remote and clearly this was assigned to the wrong remote repo.
Now I know how to change in the local repo the link to the remote ([see here for example](https://careerkarma.com/blog/git-change-remote/)), my question is:

how do I cancel from the remote repo the wrong commit I pushed?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32840254/1075282 : `If you pushed to GitHub, force pushing is not enough, delete the repository or contact support`

Comment: @Renat this only applies if the commit(s) contained sensitive information